# How to create JSON object from php string?

Tags: php, string, json

I have a large php string that consists of json style data and need to somehow convert this into a json object. My string looks like something below: (it is one BIG string). Syntax for the string isn't exactly what I attached below but it's just an example. How would I convert a string lik $string below into a json object? Thanx.

```
$string = "
{
 \"name\": \"flare\",
 \"children\": [
  {
   \"name\": \"analytics\",
   \"children\": [
    {
     \"name\": \"cluster\",
     \"children\": [
      {\"name\": \"AgglomerativeCluster\", \"size\": 3938},
      {\"name\": \"CommunityStructure\", \"size\": 3812},
      {\"name\": \"HierarchicalCluster\", \"size\": 6714},
      {\"name\": \"MergeEdge\", \"size\": 743}
     ]
    }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for this:

```
$obj = json_decode($string);
var_dump($obj);
```

Output:

```
class stdClass#1 (2) {
  public $name =>
  string(5) "flare"
  public $children =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    class stdClass#2 (2) {
      public $name =>
      string(9) "analytics"
      public $children =>
      array(1) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

What you have is a JSON Text expressed as a PHP string literal.

If you want to parse it into a PHP object, then use [`json_decode($string)`](http://php.net/json_decode).

If you want to parse it into a JavaScript object, then you have to pass the string to JavaScript somehow. That might involve printing it into the response to an HTTP request, passing it to [V8](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php) or some other technique depending on what exactly you want to achieve with it.

Comment: more clearly I am trying to use the following method: d3.json("page.php") The method can take in a .php file. My php file I am trying to pass in actually has a method within the file that creates a string like above and returns the string. Am I on the right path?

Comment: It can't take a PHP file. It can take a URL. That server might use PHP to determine what response to give to a request for that URL. (This would be the aforementioned "printing it into the response"). If you want to see what is being output, then request the URL directly by typing it into a browser's address bar.